# Eclipse android in Hello world app

Tags: android, eclipse

I am a newbie trying to learn android app development using eclipse. I installed and followed every step in the instructions.But the very default project (hello world) app is itself not running. some details might me useful:-
Eclipse luna
android apk 4.4W
jdk 1.7.0_60
OS: win8.1 x64

Error:
The emulator just says 'appname' was unfortunately closed 
I've posted some screen shots. If your could help me it would be great.
NOTE: Ive not made even a single change to the default code.

[image]

[image]

logcat:

```
07-05 05:47:33.202: D/dalvikvm(1748): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
07-05 05:47:33.362: D/AndroidRuntime(1748): Shutting down VM
07-05 05:47:33.362: W/dalvikvm(1748): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3d38ce8)
07-05 05:47:33.372: E/AndroidRuntime(1748): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-05 05:47:33.372: E/AndroidRuntime(1748): Process: com.example.testapp2, PID: 1748
07-05 05:47:33.372: E/AndroidRuntime(1748): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testapp2/com.example.testapp2.MainActivity}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine swipe dismissal and the action bar.
07-05 05:47:33.372: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2197)
07-05 05:47:33.372: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2258)
07-05 05:47:33.372: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
07-05 05:47:33.372: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1209)
07-05 05:47:33.372: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-05 05:47:33.372: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-05 05:47:33.372: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5026)
07-05 05:47:33.372: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-05 05:47:33.372: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-05 05:47:33.372: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
07-05 05:47:33.372: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
07-05 05:47:33.372: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-05 05:47:33.372: E/AndroidRuntime(1748): Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine swipe dismissal and the action bar.
07-05 05:47:33.372: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:275)
07-05 05:47:33.372: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2872)
07-05 05:47:33.372: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3129)
07-05 05:47:33.372: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:303)
07-05 05:47:33.372: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1930)
07-05 05:47:33.372: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:217)
07-05 05:47:33.372: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:110)
07-05 05:47:33.372: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:77)
07-05 05:47:33.372: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at com.example.testapp2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
07-05 05:47:33.372: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5242)
07-05 05:47:33.372: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-05 05:47:33.372: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2161)
07-05 05:47:33.372: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: To open logcat view in eclipse: Window->Show View->Other->Android->LogCat.  The logcat will show warnings/errors in your app so copy and paste it with your question.

Comment: open logcat, and at the time of the app crash, you will see a big chunk of errors(red lines of text). Copy those and paste here.
in your first image, the logcat is already open, so just paste the errors

Comment: post ur java and manifest code

Comment: please can you post your java code..

Comment: here's a link to screent shot of the logcat [link](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=r8gf41&s=8#.U7eUDvmSySo)

Comment: press Alt+Enter and then choose Android in the check android open source 4.2.2

Answer (score 0):

Yeah this is the issue after upgrading eclipse .By default it creates MainActivity extended by ActionBarActivity .Earlier it was extended to Activity.Many extra things are there now, like Fragment and other stuffs.Though you are begginner i don't  want to confuse you ,So just  replace your complete java code with below code.

```
 package `Your Package Name`;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


}

}
```

Comment: Nope this din solve the problem.... It's still showing the same
 Error..Here's the screenshot link even though i changed the main activity.java code and saved ,build and run.. the same errors pope up.here's the screenshot [link](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=x4272o&s=8#.U7fnL_mSySp)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest thing you can do to make it work:
In your project tree:

- expand your project
- expand src folder
- Expand your com.example.project_name(assuming that is the package )
- open MainAcvitiy.java
- You should replace public class `MainActivity ..........{` with `public class MainActivity extends Activity{`

Comment: After seeing your problem, I think its got something to do with the sdk versions. could you give the details of your AVD and post your manifest.xml?